# How to escape a #/# (for example 6/8) in the name of a table from a database

Tags: python

I am currently trying to get a list of values from a table inside an SQL database. The problem is appending the values due to the table's name in which I can't change. The table's name is something like Value123/123.

I tried making a variable with the name like

```
x = 'Value123/123'
```

then doing

```
row.append(x)
```

but that just prints Value123/123 and not the values from the database

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select Test, Value123/123 from db")
Test = []
Value = []
Compiled_Dict = {}
for row in cursor: 
    Test.append(row.Test)
    Value.append(row.Value123/123)
    Compiled_Dict = {'Date&Time': Test}
    Compiled_Dict['Value'] = Value
conn.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(Compiled_Dict)
```

The problem occurs in this line

```
    Value.append(row.Value123/123)
```

When I run it I get that the database doens't have a table named 'Value123'. Since I think it's trying to divide 123 by 123? Unfortunately the table in the database is named like this and I cannot change it, so how do I pull the values from this table?

Edit:

```
cursor.execute("select Test, Value123/123 as newValue from db")
```

I tried this and it worked thanks for the solutions. Suggested by Yu Jiaao

Comment: Try `Value.append(getattr(row, 'Value123/123'))`

Comment: `cursor.execute("select Test, Value123/123 as newValue from db")` and use newValue as row attribute

Comment: Try using square brackets around the column name, as in [Value123/123].